# Pie chart not displaying in aura component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura, charts, chartjs

I am developing a simple pie chart which will be included in the Accounts lightning page and I've stored Chart.js(Version 2.7.3) in static resources. However I'm struggling to get it working and no error messages in Salesforce are displayed and there is just blank space instead of the component.

My apex class:

```
public with sharing class BUOpportunityFYCV_UK {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<BUMetrics> getBUMetrics(Id accountid){
    List<BuMetrics> BUdata = new List<BuMetrics>();
    for(AggregateResult ar: [Select Sum(New_TCVP__c) Amount, Super_Group__c from Opportunity where accountid =: accountid group by Super_Group__c]){
        BUMetrics bu = new BUMetrics();
        bu.BU = (String) ar.get('Super_Group__c');
        bu.Amount = (Decimal) ar.get('Amount');
        BUdata.add(bu);
    }
    System.debug('BUdata from apex class: '+BUdata);
    return BUdata;
}

public class BUMetrics{
    @AuraEnabled
    public String BU {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    Decimal Amount {get;set;}
} 
}
```

my component:

```
<aura:component controller="BUOpportunityFYCV_UK" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.Chartjs}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />
<canvas aura:id="pie-chart" width="950" height="250"></canvas> </aura:component>
```

JS controller:

```
scriptsLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getBUMetrics");
    action.setParams({ accountid : component.get("v.recordId") });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            let val = response.getReturnValue() ;
            var labelset=[] ;
            var dataset=[] ;
            val.forEach(function(key) {
                labelset.push(key.BU) ; 
                dataset.push(key.Amount) ; 
            });
            var ctx = component.find("pie-chart").getElement();
            new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'pie',
                data: {
                    labels:labelset,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: "Total Amount",
                        //backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9"],
                        data: dataset
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Pipe by BU'
                    }
                }
            });
        }else if(state=='ERROR'){
            var error = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + 
                                errors[0].message);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Unknown error");
            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

}
```

Could someone please point out if I'm doing anything wrong?

Comment: what is your ctx var returning, have you attempted to debug a bit? validated that your var's are not undefined, that your controller values are properly fetched?

Comment: Is it working in normal HTML without lightning?

Comment: @glls I've console logged it as below
CTX ------------------> : SecureElement: [object HTMLCanvasElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }

Comment: youl probably want to set some breakpoints in your code using your borwsers devtools to pinpoint the root cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a lightning app and added a similar version of the component and since this was to be included in the lightning app I had to add "force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" in the implements attribute of the aura:component tag. It was displaying as expected in the app so added the same attributes values to my original component and it worked. So my component which is working, now looks like (rest of the code i.e. js controller and apex controller remain the same)

```
<aura:component controller="BUOpportunityFYCV_UK" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.Chartjs}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />
<canvas id="chartid" aura:id="pie-chart" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
```

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure you're missing a constructor for your inner class.

```
public class BUMetrics {
    public BUMetrics(String bu , Decimal amt) {
        this.BU = bu;
        this.Amount = amt;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public String BU {get;set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal Amount {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I highly doubt it’s the constructor mate. When one does not explicitly specify a constructor the compiler creates one for you which initialises the instance variables!